# Filtering The Woo Commerce Query Before Page Loads To Sort By Price

Tags: woocommerce

I have a product category in my Woo Commerce store called 'j-pods'.

The goal is to make a page centered around 'cheap j pods'.

So I created a new product category with the slug 'cheap-j-pods'.

When the 'cheap' variant page loads, I would like to alter the query to make it pull all products from the original 'j-pods' category, and filter them from lowest, to highest price.

From my understanding the 'woocommerce_product_query' action was the way to tinker with the main query before it is executed.

**Update:** I have found a nice way to alter the product category to be pulled, however the arrange by price part of the query is not working.

Here is my code...

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', function( $q ) {
   $pageCat = $q->get( 'product_cat' );

   if( empty($pageCat) || $pageCat !== 'cheap-j-pods') { 
       return;
   }

   // Change product category query
   $q->set( 'product_cat', 'j-pods' );

   // Extract existing meta query
   $meta_query = $q->get( 'meta_query' );

   // Add a query to arrange products by asc price
   $meta_query[] = array(   
       'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
       'meta_key' => '_price',
       'order' => 'asc'
   ); 

   //echo '<pre style="display:block">' . print_r($meta_query, true) . '</pre>';

   $q->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );

}, 900);
```

Now the products will show, but in their default order.

Why is the sort products by price not working in the query?

Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a very tidy way to make this work.

My mistake was apply the ascending price params to the 'meta query' array, whereas the values are expected in the root part of the array.

Working code below.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', function( $q ) {
    $pageCat = $q->get( 'product_cat' );

    // Only fire on specific category page
    if( empty($pageCat) || $pageCat !== 'cheap-j-pods') { 
        return;
    }

    // Change product category query
    $q->set( 'product_cat', 'j-pods' );

    // Change products to be ordered by price (lowest - highest)
    $q->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num');
    $q->set( 'meta_key', '_price');
    $q->set( 'order', 'asc');


}, 900);
```